# How to re-shape a league table into a different format using R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a league table (as a result of the `netleague` function from the `netmeta` package) that looks like this (values are made up in this example to simplify how it looks):

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.3 (-0.4 to 0.6) | . |
| 0.1 (-0.9 to 0.3) | B | -0.6 (-0.9 to 0.0 |
| 0.2 (-0.8 to 0.4) | 0.3 (-0.6 to 0.1) | C |

Where the lower triangle represents the indirect comparison (those I am interested in for this example) and reads column vs row. For instance, `0.1 (-0.9 to 0.3)` is `A vs B`.

These values are stored in R's environment as a `data.frame` within a `list` of elements.

What I would need to have as a result is:

| char1 | char2 | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 0.1 | 0.9 | 0.3 |
| A | C | 0.2 | -0.8 | 0.4 |
| B | A | -0.1 | -0.3 | 0.9 |
| B | C | 0.3 | -0.6 | 0.1 |
| C | A | -0.2 | -0.4 | 0.8 |
| C | B | -0.3 | -0.1 | 0.6 |

Please note that to obtain B vs A, I inverted the values. Depending on the nature of the outcome, I might do 1/value instead.

I tried having a look [at the code behind the `netleague` function](https://rdrr.io/cran/netmeta/src/R/netleague.R) but it is quite advanced for me to debunk it.

Does anyone have any clues on how to automate this task using R?

So far, my best option has been to either do this manually (time-consuming with more than 8000 values and likely to introduce human-made typos) or at least using some formulae in Excel (still quite time-consuming, I had to adapt the formulae row-by-row).

**Data in reproducible format:** (source: `dput(league[["fixed"]][1:4, ])`)

```
structure(list(V1 = c("dalia", "0.08 (-0.9 to  0.26)", 
"-0.15 (-0.40 to  0.06)", "0.37 ( 0.00 to  0.78)"), V2 = c("-0.05 (-0.33 to  0.22)", 
"camelia", "-0.24 (-0.49 to -0.01)", "0.31 (-0.09 to  0.75)"
), V3 = c("-0.14 (-0.64 to  0.32)", "-0.37 (-0.66 to -0.05)", 
"margher", "0.54 ( 0.12 to  0.95)"), V4 = c(".", ".", ".", 
"rosa_can"), V5 = c(".", ".", ".", "."), V6 = c(".", ".", ".", 
"."), V7 = c(".", ".", ".", "."), V8 = c("0.65 ( 0.54 to  0.87)", 
"0.54 ( 0.38 to  0.78)", "0.77 ( 0.2 to  1.28)", "0.29 (-0.08 to  0.67)"
), V9 = c(".", ".", ".", "."), V10 = c(".", ".", ".", "."), V11 = c(".", 
".", ".", "."), V12 = c("0.23 (-0.52 to  0.99)", ".", "-0.05 (-0.56 to  0.47)", 
"."), V13 = c(".", "0.07 (-0.25 to  0.33)", ".", ".")), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide data in a reproducible format? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: @RonakShah I have updated the original post - thanks, I didn't know `dput` (always good to learn!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
ff <- function(x, y, z){
  sprintf("%.1f (%.1f to %.1f)",  -as.numeric(x),
          -as.numeric(z), -as.numeric(y))
}
DT <- as.matrix(DT)
rownames(DT) <- colnames(DT) <- diag(DT)

pattern <- r"((\S+)\s+\(\s*(\S+)\s*to\s*(\S+)\))"
DT[upper.tri(DT)] <- gsubfn::gsubfn(pattern,ff, t(DT)[upper.tri(DT)])

with(subset(as.data.frame.table(DT), Var1!=Var2),
cbind(Var2, Var1, read.table(text=gsub("[()to]", " ", Freq))))                          
      

 Var2 Var1   V1   V2  V3
1    A    B  0.1 -0.9 0.3
2    A    C  0.2 -0.8 0.4
3    B    A -0.1 -0.3 0.9
4    B    C  0.3 -0.6 0.1
5    C    A -0.2 -0.4 0.8
6    C    B -0.3 -0.1 0.6
```

Comment: I tried your code and it seems almost perfect - I have noticed however that all the values that have been inverted (B vs A, for instance - I assume those encompassed by the `ff function`) have been rounded to the first decimal, which results in different numbers (yet similar, arguably) compared to the original (A vs B). Still - thanks a lot, almost there!

Comment: I checked the `sprintf` function, I didn't know it! It seems to have worked just by typing %.2f!

Comment: Should I want to have `1/V1`, `1/V2` and `1/V3` of `A vs B` as `V1`, `V2` and `V3` of `B vs A`, would you recommend to simply amend the `ff` function?

Comment: @Raphus yes. Just adjust the ff function accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first go at your problem, but I could not exact match your desired output.
SO please point out the mistakes, so I can have another round at this..

```
library(data.table)
# Sample data
DT <- fread('"A"    "0.3 (-0.4 to 0.6)"     "."
"0.1 (-0.9 to 0.3)"     "B"     "-0.6 (-0.9 to 0.0)"
"0.2 (-0.8 to 0.4)"     "0.3 (-0.6 to 0.1)"     "C"', header = FALSE)

# Code
# Get names, set as row and colnames
names.v <- diag(as.matrix(DT))
setnames(DT, new = names.v)
DT[, char2 := names.v]
#                    A                 B                  C rowname
# 1:                 A 0.3 (-0.4 to 0.6)                  .       A
# 2: 0.1 (-0.9 to 0.3)                 B -0.6 (-0.9 to 0.0)       B
# 3: 0.2 (-0.8 to 0.4) 0.3 (-0.6 to 0.1)                  C       C

# Melt to long
ans <- setcolorder(melt(DT, id.vars = "char2", variable.name = "char1"), c(2,1,3))
#    char1 char2              value
# 1:     A     A                  A
# 2:     A     B  0.1 (-0.9 to 0.3)
# 3:     A     C  0.2 (-0.8 to 0.4)
# 4:     B     A  0.3 (-0.4 to 0.6)
# 5:     B     B                  B
# 6:     B     C  0.3 (-0.6 to 0.1)
# 7:     C     A                  .
# 8:     C     B -0.6 (-0.9 to 0.0)
# 9:     C     C                  C
                
# keep relevant rows
ans <- ans[!char1 == char2, ]
# extract numeric values
ans[, paste0("val", 1:length(tstrsplit(ans$value, "[^0-9-\\.]+", perl = TRUE))) := 
      tstrsplit(ans$value, "[^0-9-\\.]+", perl = TRUE)][]
#    char1 char2              value val1 val2 val3
# 1:     A     B  0.1 (-0.9 to 0.3)  0.1 -0.9  0.3
# 2:     A     C  0.2 (-0.8 to 0.4)  0.2 -0.8  0.4
# 3:     B     A  0.3 (-0.4 to 0.6)  0.3 -0.4  0.6
# 4:     B     C  0.3 (-0.6 to 0.1)  0.3 -0.6  0.1
# 5:     C     A                  .    . <NA> <NA>
# 6:     C     B -0.6 (-0.9 to 0.0) -0.6 -0.9  0.0
```

Comment: Hi @Wimpel, thanks! The output is almost there (brilliant!!!) but I think your code uses also values from the upper triangle. For instance, your B - A combination is `0.3 -0.4 0.6` but should be the opposite of the A B combination, hence `-0.1 -0.3 0.9`.